# Reflection - check all nullable properties have values

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, nullable

I have to loop through all the properties in a few classes and check any nullable properties to see if they have a value.  How do I cast the value returned from propertyInfo.GetValue() to a generic nullable type so that I can check the HasValue property?

Code snipped for brevity:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (<Snip: Check to see that this is a nullable type>)                                                                      
    {
           //How do i cast this properly in here to allow me to do:
           if(!((Nullable)propInfo.GetValue(this, null)).HasValue)
                  //More code here
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you just do if(propInfo.GetValue(this, null) != null) ? Or do you want to explicitly use HasValue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

note I'm assuming you mean `Nullable<T>`; if you mean `Nullable<T>` or a reference, then you already have it: `object` (from `GetValue`) - just check for `null`.

In the case of `Nullable<T>`; you can't cast to a single non-generic type (other than `object`) - but you don't need to; just check that it isn't `null`, since empty `Nullable<T>` is boxed to `null`, and `GetValue` returns `object` (hence it boxes the value).

```
if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) != null) {
    // it is a Nullable<T> for some T
    if(propInfo.GetValue(this, null) != null) {
        // it has a value (it isn't an empty Nullable<T>)
    }
}
```

To clarify, `Nullable` is a static utility class that is **completely separate** to the `Nullable<T>` struct; so you don't cast to `Nullable` at all. As it happens, `Nullable` exists to provide things like the `GetUnderlyingType` that helps you work with `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Source code reference: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,134

Comment: You have twice `Nullable<T>` in the first sentence... this kind of doesn't make sense... did you mean to just say `Nullable`  & `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @t3chb0t I meant it as written; there are two very different meanings of nullable, and I was clarifying that for one of them it is automatically trivial, and in fact both of them can (via the special boxing rules) be handled in that same way - and: further: the way the OP is *trying* to do it (which involves using a more general version of Nullable-T) doesn't exist and cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've established that the property is of type `Nullable<something>`, you know *its value* has a `HasValue` property - so find that property by reflection and get its value.